# SSIS Web Service task

Tags: web-services, ssis

i have an SSIS package with a web service task, which is executed by sql server job.
the web service task is configured to call a .asxm service with the service url mentioned in .dtsConfig file.

Our testing team has tried a scenario in which, a SP was renamed in the .asmx service to ensure that service call will fail.

The .asmx service when called from SSIS failed as expected, but the job which executes the SSIS package showed success status in job history.

is this the right behavior, Is the web service task Async?

Answer (score 0):

Is the SSIS package is stored at file system, or at mssql db?

The MSSQL job agent asynchronously executes non-MSSQL jobs/steps, if stuff it executes is outside MSSQL environment, it will start external process and report success. I think that it's smarter practice if package is deployed into MSSQL Server, instead of file system.

It also depends how you handle task errors/results within package, you could implement alerting, raise an error etc...

Here are some links about sync/async Job executions at MSSQL 2k12:

[Execute a SSIS package in sync or async mode from SQL Server 2012](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/davide_mauri/archive/2011/11/24/execute-a-ssis-package-in-sync-or-async-mode-from-sql-server-2012.aspx)

[Different ways to execute a SQL Server SSIS package](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1775/different-ways-to-execute-a-sql-server-ssis-package/)